# What are some different types of device motion gestures?

Tags: input, hardware, motion-control, gestures

Complex touch events are well-defined and can even be categorised as seen in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_device_gesture#Touchpad_and_touchscreen_gestures)

We have great names for various touch gestures like:

- Double-tap
- Pinch / Zoom
- Long Press
- etc.

When it comes to whole-device motion gestures, I can only think of a few:

- Shake
- Figure-8
- Horizontal Slice (ie: quickly move back an forth without rotation)

Is there a similar list for whole-device motion gestures?

Comment: Re-orienting comes to mind (eg. tilting side to side, switching landscape vs portrait, or inverting for wormholes in Space Team). I don't know whether this can be answered with a definitive list of significant gestures though. Are you looking for gestures that serve a particular function, or anything else we could use as a criterion to identify a good or correct answer?